# Add each element of an RDD to each element of another RDD in spark scala.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDDs with following structure

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Double)]
```

Here each row of RDD contains an index `Long` and a value `Double`. I want to add each element of an RDD to each element of other RDD in spark scala.

An example would look like this:

RDD1:

```
Array[(Long, Double)] = Array((0,-3),(1,2))
```

RDD2:

```
Array[(Long, Double)] = Array((0,4),(1,-2))
```

Result:

```
Array[(Long, Double)] = Array((0,1),(0,-5),(1,6),(1,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really doing here is a cartesian product of your two `rdd`'s, where you simply sum the *values* of each resulting `((key, value), (key, value))` pair, keeping the *key* of the first tuple:

```
val result = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).map(x => (x._1._1, x._2._2 + x._1._2))
// Result
result.collect()
Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,1), (0,-5), (1,6), (1,0))
```

Be careful using `cartesian()` though, memory consumption will dramatically increase the bigger your `rdd`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
val df1 = Seq((0,-3),(1,2)).toDF("col1", "col2")
val df2 = Seq((0,4),(1,-2)).toDF("col1", "col2")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")

spark.sql("SELECT t1.col1 + t2.col1, t1.col2 + t2.col2 FROM t1, t2").show
```

Answer (score 0):

zip the two RDDs and then map over that to calculate the sums